# Qt StyleSheet to programmatically createdQWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I want to apply a stylesheet to a particular `Qwidget` that I create in the constructor of the parent `QWidget`. I don't want to create the `QWidget` in the Designer, but I want to create it dynamically.

This is my code

```
enum {one = 0,
two = 1,
three = 2};

cMainForm::cMainForm(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::cMainForm) {

//...

QWidget* widgetTest[3];
widgetTest[one] = new QWidget(this);
widgetTest[one]->setGeometry(100,100,100,100);
widgetTest[one]->show();
widgetTest[one]->raise();

//...

 setStyleSheet("QWidget#widgetTest[one]{"
            "background-color: red;"
            "}"
            );

//...

}
```

And doesn't work.

If I change the styleSheet:

```
 setStyleSheet("QWidget{"
            "background-color: red;"
            "}"
            );
```

The stylesheet is applied to all the widgets. But I don't want this; I want to apply the stylesheet only to that particular widget.

Also if I don't use an array, it doesn't work.

```
QWidget* widgetTest;
widgetTest = new QWidget(this);
widgetTest->setGeometry(100,100,100,100);
widgetTest->show();
widgetTest->raise();

//...

 setStyleSheet("QWidget#widgetTest{"
            "background-color: red;"
            "}"
            );
```

I already searched the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html).

What's the solution?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean exactly?

Comment: The background of the widget isn't red, as  it is supposed to be

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The selector you're using (`#`) refers to the widget `objectName` property, not the variable name (the style engine knows nothing about your variables). Give the widget an object name:

```
widgetTest->setObjectName("widgetTest");
```

then set the stylesheet:

```
widgetTest->setStyleSheet("QWidget#widgetTest { background-color: red }");
```

Comment: Many thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for